# prevent kernel message which appears on terminal screen /dev/tty1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, logging, kernel

Kernel debug level message

> watchdog : BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s!

appears in my console(/dev/tty1) and I am trying to prevent it.

I tried following 3 methods but none of them worked:

1. I set kernel.printk = 1 1 1 1 in file /etc/sysctl.conf. Running sysctl kernel.printk from command line I can affirm the values are correct.
2. Running dmesg -n 1 and dmesg -D (console off)
3. I tried  to set /etc/systemd/journald.conf values ForwardToConsole=no and TTYPath=/dev/tty2 ForwardToWall=no

None of these helped and kernel log still prints on my terminal.

What is missing? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I misunderstood the priority level of this log message because of the word "BUG" in it. I thought it is a debug message with priority 7. However when I checked with commands "journalctl -k -p 0" and "dmesg --level=emerg" I see that priority level of the message is zero.

So setting kernel.printk = 0 0 0 0 in file /etc/sysctl.conf solved the problem.